# extracting data from tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

very simple question for BS4 expert....!
I need to assign this "SALE" tag  into a  variable "variable"

```
> > <strong class="product-tag product-tag--on-sale ">    <span>SALE</span>
> > </strong>
```

> 

```
> X = soup.find('strong', class_="product-tag product-tag--on-sale
> ").text.strip()
```

not working...('NoneType' object has no attribute 'text')

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
h = '''<strong class="product-tag product-tag--on-sale ">
<span>SALE</span>
</strong>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('strong', class_='product-tag--on-sale').find('span').text.strip())
```

```
SALE
```